# Is there any similarity between $timeout, $interval(), and a $watch()

Tags: angularjs

Is there any similarity between `$timeout`, `$interval`, and  `$watch()` explain with some example

Comment: Similarity with regard to what?

Comment: Considering the precision of the question, the only answer I can give you is **Yes**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a real difference between $interval and $timeout in this use case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231513/is-there-a-real-difference-between-interval-and-timeout-in-this-use-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$timeout** and **$interval** are somewhat similar. Both execute a given function after a given time. **$timeout** does this one time, **$interval** does this repeatedly.

**$watch** can observe an expression (eg. a $scope property) and execute a function every time a change has occurred.